# Riemann Sum approaches Area under Curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations, calc

I am trying to write a program where I can change the number of subintervals, n( using \def\n\some number), and the output show that specific number of rectangles in the Riemann Sum. An animation would be great if possible, but the black lines and filled red circles may cause a problem when n is large? I hope I made my intentions clear. Here is my MWE. Have fun! I am interested in all answers!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2,declare function={f(\x)=((1/3)*(\x)^(3)-3*(\x)^(2)+8*\x-3;}]
\coordinate (start) at (.8,{f(.8)});
\coordinate (x0) at (1,{f(1)});
\coordinate (x1) at (2,{f(2)});
\coordinate (x2) at (3,{f(3)});
\coordinate (x3) at (4,{f(4)});
\coordinate (x4) at (5,{f(5)});
\coordinate (end) at (5.05,{f(5.05)});
\draw[fill=orange!40!white] (1,0) rectangle (2,{f(1)});
\draw[fill=orange!40!white] (2,0) rectangle (3,{f(2)});
\draw[fill=orange!40!white] (3,0) rectangle (4,{f(3)});
\draw[fill=orange!40!white] (4,0) rectangle (5,{f(4)});
\draw (5,0)--(5,{f(5)});
\draw [-latex] (-0.5,0) -- (6,0) node (xaxis) [below] {$x$};
\draw [-latex] (0,-0.5) -- (0,5) node [left] {$y$};
\foreach \x/\xtext in {1/a=x_{1} ,2/x_{2}, 3/x_{3} , 4/x_{4} , 5/b }
 \draw[xshift=\x cm] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,0pt) 
node[below=2pt,fill=white,font=\normalsize]
  {$\xtext$};
\draw[domain=.5:5.3,samples=200,variable=\x,red,<->,thick] plot ({\x},{f(\x)});                 
\foreach \n in {0,1,2,3}
\draw[red,fill=red] (x\n) circle (2pt) node[font=\normalsize] {$$};    
\draw[<->] (2,-1)--(3,-1) node[above,midway] {$\Delta x$};      
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This outputs:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an animation. Big thanks to JouleV for pushing me to improve on the labels. (Now I appreciate even more what pgfplots does out of the box.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\foreach \N in {4,5,...,21}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2,declare function={f(\x)=((1/3)*(\x)^(3)-3*(\x)^(2)+8*\x-3;},
lnode/.style={fill=white,font=\normalsize,inner sep=0pt,text height=1.5em}]
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\M}{\N/4}
 \coordinate (start) at (.8,{f(.8)});
 \foreach \X [remember=\X as \LastX (initially 0)] in {1,...,\N}
 {\draw[fill=orange!40!white] (1+\LastX*4/\N,0) rectangle (1+\X*4/\N,{f(1+\LastX*4/\N)});
 \draw[red,fill=red] (1+\LastX*4/\N,{f(1+\LastX*4/\N)}) circle (2pt) ;
 \path  (1+\LastX*4/\N,0pt) coordinate (x\X);
 \ifnum\X=1
  \draw (1+\LastX*4/\N,3pt) -- (1+\LastX*4/\N,0pt) coordinate (x\X)
    node[anchor=north east,xshift=2pt,lnode]  {$a=x_{\X}$};
   \else
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{mod(\X,\M)}
     \ifnum\itest=0
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\dist}{4-\LastX*4/\N}
        \ifdim\dist cm>5pt
          \draw (1+\LastX*4/\N,3pt) -- (1+\LastX*4/\N,0pt)
           node[anchor=north,lnode] {$x_{\X}$};  
        \fi  
     \fi
  \fi
 }
 \coordinate (end) at (5.05,{f(5.05)});
 \draw (5,3pt) -- (5,0pt)
 node[anchor=north west,xshift=-2pt,lnode]{$b$};
 \draw (5,0)--(5,{f(5)});
 \draw [-latex] (-0.5,0) -- (6,0) node (xaxis) [below] {$x$};
 \draw [-latex] (0,-0.5) -- (0,5) node [left] {$y$};
 \draw[domain=.5:5.3,samples=200,variable=\x,red,<->,thick] plot ({\x},{f(\x)});                 
 \draw[<->] (x2|- 0,-1)--(x3|- 0,-1) node[above,midway] {$\Delta x$};      
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for your additional request:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\foreach \N in {4,5,...,25}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2,declare function={f(\x)=((1/3)*(\x)^(3)-3*(\x)^(2)+8*\x-3;},
lnode/.style={fill=white,font=\normalsize,inner sep=0pt,text height=1.5em}]
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\M}{\N/4}
 \coordinate (start) at (.8,{f(.8)});
 \ifnum\N<22
   \foreach \X [remember=\X as \LastX (initially 0)] in {1,...,\N}
   {\draw[fill=orange!40!white] (1+\LastX*4/\N,0) rectangle (1+\X*4/\N,{f(1+\LastX*4/\N)});
   \draw[red,fill=red] (1+\LastX*4/\N,{f(1+\LastX*4/\N)}) circle (2pt) ;
   \path  (1+\LastX*4/\N,0pt) coordinate (x\X);
   \ifnum\X=1
    \draw (1+\LastX*4/\N,3pt) -- (1+\LastX*4/\N,0pt) coordinate (x\X)
      node[anchor=north east,xshift=2pt,lnode]  {$a=x_{\X}$};
     \else
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{mod(\X,\M)}
       \ifnum\itest=0
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\dist}{4-\LastX*4/\N}
          \ifdim\dist cm>5pt
            \draw (1+\LastX*4/\N,3pt) -- (1+\LastX*4/\N,0pt)
             node[anchor=north,lnode] {$x_{\X}$};  
          \fi  
       \fi
    \fi
   }
   \draw[<->] (x2|- 0,-1)--(x3|- 0,-1) node[above,midway] {$\Delta x$};      
 \else
   \draw[fill=orange!40!white]
   plot[domain=1:5,samples=167,variable=\x] ({\x},{f(\x)})
   -- (5,0) -| cycle;
 \fi
 \coordinate (end) at (5.05,{f(5.05)});
 \draw (5,3pt) -- (5,0pt)
 node[anchor=north west,xshift=-2pt,lnode]{$b$};
 \draw (5,0)--(5,{f(5)});
 \draw [-latex] (-0.5,0) -- (6,0) node (xaxis) [below] {$x$};
 \draw [-latex] (0,-0.5) -- (0,5) node [left] {$y$};
 \draw[domain=.5:5.3,samples=200,variable=\x,red,<->,thick] plot ({\x},{f(\x)});                 
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just started looking at this and I notice the delta x looks wrong. First I am trying to understand the program  by doing non animation first. When I just place a '12' in the forall command everything looks good but the Delta is not right?!

Comment: @MathScholar Yes, you are right, fixed it.

Comment: this is working but I have one last question for the day. How can I make the last four frames be the actual area under the curve. In your case above how can I tell N=22,23,24 and 25 to be the area under the curve itself? Thank you very much

Comment: @MathScholar I added something along those lines.

Comment: Excellent work Marmot! This has been very helpful!